# Mpdf\MpdfException: Word is too long to fit in table

Tags: php, mpdf

When I try to parse my html data which contain tables, it gives me error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Word is too long to fit in
>   table - in
>   /home/users/rajat.agarwal/www/html/mve_493_sp3/app/addons/wk_invoice/lib/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php
>   on line 19056

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->use_kwt = true;
// $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$html = '
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Your table data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</div>
';
$mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;
$mpdf->table_error_report = true;
// $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=0;
$mpdf->WriteHTML(
    $html
);
$mpdf->Output();exit;
```

I have already tried many solution like `autosize="1"` or `$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=0`; but not one works for me.

Composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0"
}}
```

Comment: Why did you enable undocumented `table_error_report`? Is the code working as expected when you remove it?